# Usar .htaccess em um diretório com arquivo e pastas com mesmo nome

Tags: apache, htaccess, url

Meu diretório é o seguinte:

```
root/
├── index.php
├── about.php
├── privacy.php
└── about/
    ├── brand.php
    └── history.php
```

Gostaria que, quando o usuário digitasse `meusite.com/about`, o HTACCESS o redirecionasse para o arquivo `about.php`. Entretanto, se o usuário digitar `meusite.com/about/`, o HTACCESS deve usar a pasta, acessando os aquivos contidos naquele diretório.

Seria a *trailing slash* que definirá se a URL irá a um diretório ou a um arquivo.

É possível fazer isto?

---

**EDIT 2**

Consegui fazer com que as URL ficassem padronizadas — ou seja, com uma barra sempre ao fim delas — e, ao mesmo tempo, retornassem a página correta, removendo a extensão `.php`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^about/brand/$ /about/brand.php [NC,L]
```

A droga é ter que adicionar tudo manual. Mas estou ainda buscando um resultado melhor.

Comment: é possível, basta colocar a condição sem a barra no .htaccess para o PHP. Seria mais fácil você dizer o que tentou e explicar o que deu de errado, pois a solução que você procura é igual qualquer outra, o fato de ser uma barra ou um nome inteiramente diferente não muda muita coisa.

Comment: Agora, não é mais fácil salvar o about.php como about/index.php simplesmente, e deixar tudo com barra?

Comment: @Bacco Mas aí o site ficaria com URLs que possuem a trailing slash e outras, não. Por exemplo: `meusite.com/about/` e `meusite.com/about/brand`. Ao meu ver, neste caso, o HTACCESS teria que adicionar a trailing slash faltante, correto?

Comment: Quanto a variar a barra no final, tem razão. Sobre adicionar a barra, isso é bem simples, basta uma regra que teste se é diretório e tem barra no final. Não é complicado isso que você quer, mas se [edit] a pergunta e puser um .htaccess de ponto de partida ajuda, pois além de poder partir de algo dentro do que você domina, ou tem uma noção, fica mais fácil ajustar do que fazer um do zero, que possa conflitar com algo mais que você queira. Além disso, é bom já mencionar outras situações. Por exemplo, o que é para acontecer se a pessoa acessar /about.php em vez de só /about ? Tem esses detalhes.

Comment: Opa, melhorou bastante com o edit. Parece que está no caminho certo, provavelmente precisa só de alguns ajustes. Não sei se ajudaria trocar o 3º rule por  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`, e acho que dá pra dar umas simplificadas em algumas coisas.

Comment: A não ser que eu somente deixe uma regra para adicionar a trailing slash e depois edito por `RewriteRule ^about/brand/$ /about/brand.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Se ninguém responder e sobrar um tempo mais tarde, vou dar uma lida com calma e ver se consigo ver onde melhorar (não prometo, pq tou meio enrolado com umas coisas aqui), mas se eu der uma sossegada nas pendencias aqui eu dou uma pensada em cima do que você postou (pq aí dá pra eu fazer uns testes, mais fácil do que tentar só imaginar).

Comment: Olha, @Bacco. Acho que consegui resolver sozinho. A droga é que vou ter que adicionar os caminhos manualmente no HTACCESS. Vou deixar o que eu fiz no `EDIT 2`.

Comment: Dá pra fazer "automático" naquela sua linha de testar se existe com .php no fim, provavelmente é algum ajuste simples (ou eliminar alguma regra que esteja atrapalhando, ao menos para teste)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta ver assim:

```
# Reescreve as solicitações .php originais em novas URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R,L]

# Força a adição da trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..{3,4}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

# Redireciona para .PHP se não existe diretório
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Esse código funcionou. Obrigado, Cernuno.